# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null, while firing a get request

Tags: java, android, apache, http

I will appreciate your help on this, below is the code am trying to execute, but all am getting is this exception, I did many changes, but am not able to resolve this.

Please let me know if you have any pointers, am running on android 4.4.4

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://s3­-eu-­west-­1.amazonaws.com/developer-application-­test/cart/list");
resp = client.execute(request);

01-22 22:25:03.885: W/System.err(14697): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
01-22 22:25:03.886: W/System.err(14697):    at org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:83)
01-22 22:25:03.886: W/System.err(14697):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:508)
01-22 22:25:03.886: W/System.err(14697):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:498)
01-22 22:25:03.886: W/System.err(14697):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:476)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @atish shimpi mentioned, this is most likely due to an improperly formatted URL. I typed up the following code snipped and debugged it on a development phone:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
URI url = new URI("https://s3-eu­west­1.amazonaws.com/developer-application­test/cart/list");
URI url1 = new URI("https://www.google.com/");
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

As you can see, I added another `URI` object which points to `https://www.google.com/` to use as a comparison. When I debugged, I set breakpoints on the creation of both `URI` objects. Upon creating the corresponding `URI` object for the address you provided, the `host` field is `null`...

[image]

However, when I create a similiar `URI` object for the Google address, the `host` field is not `null`, which means something is wrong with your address...

[image]

I am still not quite sure why the method `URI(String spec)` fails to resolve the proper fields. This might be a bug or it might just be related to your specific URL. Regardless, I was able to finally process the request by taking the link you provided and manually creating a `URI` object as follows:

```
URI uri = new URI("https", "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com", "/developer-application-test/cart/list", null, null);
```

Using this manually created `URI`, I was able to download the list that you created:

```
"products" : [
    {
    "product_id" : "1",
    "name" : "Apples",
    "price" : 120,
    "image" : "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/developer-application-test/images/1.jpg"
    },
    {
    "product_id" : "2",
    "name" : "Oranges",
    "price" : 167,
    "image" : "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/developer-application-test/images/2.jpg"
    },
    {
    "product_id" : "3",
    "name" : "Bananas",
    "price" : 88,
    "image" : "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/developer-application-test/images/3.jpg"
    },
etc....
```

As a reference point, here is my final working code:

```
try
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    URI uri = new URI("https", "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com", "/developer-application-test/cart/list", null, null);
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    if (httpEntity != null)
    {
        InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String currentLine = null;
        while ((currentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(currentLine + "\n");
        }
        String result = stringBuilder.toString();
        Log.v("Http Request Results:",result);
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Good workaround, although the initial problem still strange and unresolved. Bug report?

Comment: this is so stupid, making URI by part does helped in getting uri right, but still in one shot system is not able to parse the uri correct.

Comment: No luck? You are still having the same issue?

Comment: We had the same issue. It seems to be a "-" and "_" issue. We created a new vhost with a simpler url and this issues disappeared. Note: this is not a solution. I'm just giving my 2 cents to figure out what the cause could be.

Answer (score -2):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
```

Issue came because of your URL check your URL `"https://s3­eu­west­1.amazonaws.com/developer­application­test/cart/list"`

Comment: my bad I have updated my question, i pasted correct url but formatted removed hyphen.

Comment: @Techfist so you still got the same error, even with the proper URL now in your question?